# Exact times in "docker ps" and "docker images"

Tags: docker

`docker ps` and `docker images` express times in a rather vague fashion, e.g. "About an hour ago" or "2 days ago". How can I discover the exact times?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use [`docker inspect`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/):

```
docker inspect -f '{{ .Created }}' IMAGE_OR_CONTAINER
```

Comment: Or, to get the exact uptime for a container:

`docker inspect -f '{{ .State.StartedAt }}' CONTAINER_ID`

Answer (score 24):

The question is asking how to display the exact times when using `docker ps` and `docker images`.  This can be accomplished directly with a format argument, using CreatedAt

```
$ docker ps --format 'table {{.ID}}\t{{.Command}}\t{{.CreatedAt}}'
CONTAINER ID        COMMAND                  CREATED AT
86baa3a5058a        "./env.sh catalina.s…"   2019-10-30 08:30:15 -0400 EDT   
1eb21e95119d        "./env.sh catalina.s…"   2019-10-30 06:58:34 -0400 EDT   
87be4be4c328        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2019-10-30 06:58:33 -0400 EDT   
e4ab699631c8        "./env.sh catalina.s…"   2019-10-30 06:58:32 -0400 EDT
```

The `table` specification adds the headers.  The legal format fields are documented, for example at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#formatting, but mostly correspond to the capitalized column headers, so you could add `{{.Ports}}` to the format above. (From the reference, you can also see all the field names like `docker ps --format='{{json .}}'`)

`docker inspect` (from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28203469/500902) can be used to display the time for a single image or container, uses a different format property `{{.Created}}` and displays the time format slightly differently, for no obvious reason.

Answer (score 1):

As others have shown, a dump of `docker inspect` exposes the `Created` field, and using the filter of `{{.Created}}` will allow you to search the JSON array, match the corresponding key, and isolate the value output.

Example against a pihole/pihole container:

```
$ docker inspect -f '{{.Created}}' pihole/pihole
2022-09-05T11:32:56.256782646Z
```

You can see an example of how this works in a JSON playground, here: https://jqplay.org/s/pbCt0n1Qva6

To make this further usable, we can use other tools, such as `date` to reformat this data to an Epoch timestamp:

```
$ date --date "$(docker inspect -f '{{.Created}}' pihole/pihole)" +'%s'
1662377576
```

From here, you should be able to apply any maths or alternate displays of the date that fit your needs. We could go with an RFC 3339 compliant timestamp like this:

```
$ date --rfc-3339 seconds --date @"1662377576"
2022-09-05 04:32:56-07:00
```

Since the epoch represents seconds, dividing by `86400` (how many seconds in a day) would give you days for some basic approximations, etc, or even simply just:

```
$ date -d @1662377576
Mon Sep  5 04:32:56 PDT 2022
```