# How to get exact date for docker images?

Tags: docker

I run `docker images` and get something like this:

```
REPOSITORY            TAG       IMAGE ID        CREATED        VIRTUAL SIZE
docker.io/postgres    latest    a7d662bede59    2 weeks ago    265.3 MB
docker.io/ubuntu      latest    91e54dfb1179    2 weeks ago    188.3 MB
```

Look at `CREATED` column. I want to know what image created earlier with hours, minutes, seconds. Similar with containers, for command `docker ps -a`. How to view exact dates?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Use `docker inspect`:

```
docker inspect -f '{{ .Created }}' IMAGE_OR_CONTAINER
```

From: [Exact times in "docker ps" and "docker images"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28203413/exact-times-in-docker-ps-and-docker-images)

Comment: That will work, but I got a strange error `Template parsing error: template: :1: unexpected unclosed action in command` when executing it.

Comment: Try removing the spaces inside the curly braces

Comment: But what if you don't the IMAGE_OR_CONTAINER? That is I why I need the exact date/time.

Answer (score 60):

You can use the `--format` parameter to output `CreatedAt` instead of `CreatedSince`:

```
docker images --format "table {{.Repository}}\t{{.Tag}}\t{{.ID}}\t{{.CreatedAt}}\t{{.Size}}"
```

See [the command line reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#format-the-output) for more info.

Comment: I think this is the real answer to the question as it builds upon the original docker images command, but formats it correctly such that you can see proper creation dates. Furthermore you can get the whole list of images and their creation dates at the same time, without knowing the IDs.

Answer (score 10):

I think the best way would be to run `docker inspect IMAGE_OR_CONTAINER`, then pipe the output to grep to filter the results to what you really want.

If you only want to know when it started, run

`docker inspect IMAGE_OR_CONTAINER | grep -i created`

... which results in the following output:

```
"Created": "2015-09-18T01:46:51.471641483Z",
```

That's pretty clean.

... you could do the same for "started":

`docker inspect IMAGE_OR_CONTAINER | grep -i started`

... which results in the following output:

```
"StartedAt": "2015-09-18T01:46:51.79789586Z"
```

Comment: Images do not have "StartedAt" attribute. Only containers.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to Dag's answer, you can permanently change the format of the output from `docker images` by adding your custom format to your ~/.docker/config.json file:

```
"imagesFormat": "table {{.Repository}}\\t{{.Tag}}\\t{{.ID}}\\t{{.Size}}\\t{{.CreatedAt}}"
```

Comment: What is ~/.docker/config.json about: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/#configjson-properties

Comment: Nice! So if this is only configured in your local docker, but you want nice output in a remote invocation: `ssh foo@bar docker images --format "$(jq .imagesFormat < ~/.docker/config.json)"` (using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/))

Comment: This is GOLD, the vague modern virtually useless "times" have been driving me mad!