# Use timestamp retrieved from data store instead of file for invalidation

Tags: makefile

I am trying to create a makefile to automate my build commands for creating Docker containers. The docker repo keeps track of the date an image was built, but there's no physical file to reference. In this case I can [get an ISO-style date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32705176/how-to-get-exact-date-for-docker-images) a la `2016-04-11T23:22:32.867870925Z` that I'm sure I can parse into a timestamp variable.

But in the general case this value could come from any off-machine data store, which is becoming much more common in contemporary devops processes. Invalidating a make target based on a variable value instead of a physical file is not something I can seem to find any info on.

If I need to use a proxy timestamp file, that's fine I suppose, just curious if there is a better way.

Comment: I doubt there is a better way. Make is designed to use file timestamps; the only approaches to a workaround I can see are an ugly proxy-timestamp hack, and deep operating-system demonology.

Comment: It would be great to have such feature. I also create dummy files (touch $@) to track docker images and containers.