# In docker inspect, what do "StartedAt" and "FinishedAt" mean?

Tags: docker

This is the result of running `docker inspect` on a running container:

```
$ docker inspect some_container | jq .[0].State
{
  "Status": "running",
  "Running": true,
  "Paused": false,
  "Restarting": false,
  "OOMKilled": false,
  "Dead": false,
  "Pid": 16086,
  "ExitCode": 0,
  "Error": "",
  "StartedAt": "2021-09-16T02:36:12.036585245Z",
  "FinishedAt": "2021-09-16T04:36:10.87103895+02:00"
}
```

Nobody was logged into that system at the times listed in the `StartedAt` and `FinishedAt` entries, and it doesn't seem like the container was restarted after a crash:

```
$ docker inspect lxonlinedlservice_rabbitmq_1 | grep RestartCount
        "RestartCount": 0,
```

What do the `StartedAt` and `FinishedAt` entries mean?

Comment: Weird that they are in different timezones!

Comment: @phuzi Yep, it seems that the "starting" process lasted 2 seconds, except if we subtract 02:00 from `FinishedAt`, we end up two seconds *before* `StartedAt` :|

Answer (score 1):

From [github](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/fe2008d04e80fafd6cab19d70169b06432a47c6d/vendor/k8s.io/api/core/v1/types_swagger_doc_generated.go#L405)

- `startedAt` - `Time at which previous execution of the container started`
- `finishedAt` - `Time at which the container last terminated`

You mentioned crash. Maybe container started after a crash at `2021-09-16T02:36:12.036585245Z` and at  `2021-09-16T04:36:10.87103895+02:00` there was another crash?

Or, might it me that docker host where the container runs was rebooted?

Suggest also to check that your clock is synced using `ntp`. Check [this](https://docs.docker.com/develop/dev-best-practices/#differences-in-development-and-production-environments) docker best practice.

Answer (score 0):

To get the exact uptime for a container: docker inspect -f '{{ .State.StartedAt }}' CONTAINER_ID
StartedAt: when you started your image or container
FinishedAt: when you stopped your image or container
(from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28203469/500902)